# Sublime Text 3: any package to print out the tree of a specific function?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Let's say we want to know who uses the function:

```
function function_name (){}
```

How to print out something like...

```
a.php -> line 56 -> $something = function_name();
b.php -> line 20 -> $other = function_name($variable_name);
```

Comment: Why not just use Find in Files and search for the function name?

Comment: @MattDMo because I got overwhelmed with a lot of names and functions. Actually, I usually perform the "tree" task by hand with pen and sheet.